# React Native Submit Form Data with Navigation and Dealing with Managing Screens

Tags: react-native, design-patterns, architecture

Whats the best practice for dealing with forms where I would want to have multiple (of the same) forms being "saved" (maybe in a JSON format somewhere) before actually saving it to database or doing something with it.

The idea is user will have multiple images, and then each image will have its own screen with text input fields to apply the information they can save to describe the image. Then user will click on "next" and the screen will slide next with empty forms and next image. This will continue until the end of the array of images, then user will "complete" all information.

I'm assuming that I'll be using 1 component because the format is going to be the same, but how do I get it it'll be the same component with empty forms and where all the information is stored somewhere?

edit: would also need this to work on video components.

Comment: I think you  can achieve what u want with some abstraction and formik multistep example. Formik works with react native https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik/blob/master/examples/MultistepWizard.js

Comment: You can try a simple horizontal scroll view with pagination enabled.

Comment: i would create a global Helper varialbe as an array to store data with push each form as string, and then a full horizental paged flatlish then full it with the stored data in the global helper

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to involve multiple state in your compoenents. so you can change your state in your component and show what do you want.

https://github.com/archriss/react-native-snap-carousel/issues/102

You can refer this link and you can get idea how to do it.

Comment: I don't think I would do it like that, I think I would reuse the component, and just have 1 screen (1 image and details) be showing. Then when it goes next, thats where user will see the next image. I guess it would be similar to like a checkout flow. Shipping Address Screen => Payment Option Screen => Review Screen. But for me, i'm not too sure how I should structure the data and everything that goes along with it.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're asking about is a viewPager:
example library: [react-native-viewpager](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-viewpager)

The parent component which will host the viewpager, can have the centralized info that each sub-component generates inside the view pager. When any data change inside the sub-component, you can send it via a callback prop to the parent.

(Since the layout of each sub-component is the same, then you can reuse it of course inside the view-pager).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, seems that you are dealing with a feature that involves certain flow of screens and you need to collect the user input through them.

With [React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/) you will be able to create a simple Navigation structure that allows you to navigate through different instances of the same screen component, which would hold your form ui and its own state.

Then, all input data entered by user in a form screen, you can pass it to the next screen through the [params](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/params.html) of the route. Finally, when you reach the lats screen, simply extract the whole collected data from params and push it to the database.

This doesn't provide any kind of local persistence if the user closes the app in the middle of the screen sequence.

If you need some recommended library to collect images and video from user here is [react-native-image-crop-picker](https://github.com/ivpusic/react-native-image-crop-picker)

Cheers!